# Spring Integration - How to add message on topic before sending back acknowledgement for SOAP web service using declarative approach

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-kafka

I am consuming SOAP web service using inbound-gateway.We need to put message in kafka topic and return a synchronous acknowledgement to requestor using declarative way of spring integration. Is this possible ?

```
    public Acknowledgement process(@RequestPayload MessagePayload payload) {
    // perform validation & logic
    // need to send message to kafka topic using declarative way

    // sending synchronous ack to request originator
    return new Acknowledgement(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [kafka outbound channel adapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/_spring_integration.html#si-outbound) has a `sync` property `setSync(true)` when using java config `sync="true"` when using XML.

The calling thread (web container) will block until kafka assumes responsibility. If you use a publish-subscribe channel, make the kafka adapter the first consumer, and a service to build the `Acknowledgement` the second consumer (use the `order` property in the consumers to ensure proper ordering).

Or you can use a `KafkaTemplate` directly from your controller.

Comment: My workflow is like this, consume SOAP message using above process() method -> do validations & business logic -> send to kafka topic -> return ack back to requestor using Acknowledgement object, challenge is how to use declarative way to do this.